# Visual foxpro Replace commands / CMD

Tags: foxpro

I want to make a program in foxpro where  you can type a name in a textbox and it will automatic add a user in command prompt. So netuser ( name ) and a button (add user )
Regards

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* Does the initial setting for foxpro
*
set echo off
set talk off
set step off
set date british
set century on
set intensity off
set delimiter on
set delimiter to '[]'
set scoreboard off
set menu off
set safety off
set deleted on
set escape on
set device to screen
set color to
set exclusive on
set status on
set bell off
clear all
clear program
clear
*
** define a variable to store user name to be created

muser_name = space(20) 
@ 12, 22 say 'Enter User Name ' get muser_name
read
if !empty(muser_name)
   * this command adds a new user to the computer
   run net user &muser_name /add
endif
wait
clear
clear program
return
**
* end of program
```

This will create a new user to your computer without any password.

Comment: that's what i am looking for..!  I am still study is there a way to get the code into a form design?

Comment: Foxpro does not have concept of forms & buttons like languages like VB.NET or C#. But you can certainly draw borders. Syntax is                                                                    @ <row1>, <col1> to <row2>, <col2>

Comment: Of course it has forms, and form classes, and visual controls like buttons placed on them, and code attached to those controls like .NET languages. The implementation is different but especially when using WinForms in .NET the concept is very much the same. In .NET even if you use a visual designer this just generates code to define the UI. In Visual FoxPro the metadata for forms etc is in VCX/VCT files.

Comment: I was talking about foxpro & not visual foxpro.

Comment: That still has forms (screens) & controls, in fact they're even more like the .NET WinForms world as the screen builder is just a code generator.

Comment: Anyways there is a easy way to understand how to convert program code into form design? 

thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking at Powershell instead of Visual Foxpro. 
If you are using Foxpro 2.6 (not a Visual version) you could use the Accept command:

```
DO WHILE .t.
   ACCEPT "Enter username:" to mUser
   IF len(trim(mUser)) = 0
       exit
   ENDIF
   run net user &mUser /add
ENDDO
```

Comment: Um, maybe he's writing a Visual FoxPro application that needs to do this? Absolutely he could run a PowerShell cmdlet from within it though.